# Need help in deriving condition for quartic to have only one double root

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

Given a polynomial of degree four: $ax^4+bx^3+cx^2+dx+e$, with $a,b,c,d,e$ real and $a\neq 0$, how do I derive the condition for there to be exactly distinct 3 real roots (i.e., one root is repeated)? I know that the discriminant is zero when there is a double root. But how do I enforce the condition that there be *only* one double root?

If this is known, a link to the resource would be appreciated. If not, helpful guidance in how to proceed will be nice. If you already know the answer, that would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\alpha$ is a root of order $m>1$, then $(x-\alpha)^{m-1}$ must be a common factor of your polynomial $p(x)$ and its derivative $p'(x)$. So you run Euclid's algorithm to find $d(x)=gcd(p(x),p'(x))$. It must be linear in order to $p(x)$ have exactly one (necessarily) double root. Check that the roots of $p(x)/d(x)^2$ are real to make sure that there are 3 real roots.

I don't know, if this is the kind of answer that you wanted, though?

Comment: Thanks for the response. So I tried reducing $p(x)$ by $(x-\alpha)^2$ and $p'(x)$ by $(x-\alpha)$. From each of these, I get quotients $q_1(x)$, $q_2(x)$ and remainders $r_1(x)$, $r_2(x)$ respectively. Would I be correct in saying that if $r_1$ and $r_2$ are both zero, then it is satisfied?

Comment: @doob:  You still might have to worry that the roots of $q_1(x)$ might not be real. Also, the point of calculating the gcd of $p(x)$ and $p'(x)$ was that you don't need to guess what $\alpha$ (=the double root) is. You are familiar with Euclid's algorithm, aren't you? Also, if $p(x)$ is divisible by $(x-\alpha)^2$, then there is no need to check the divisibility of $p'(x)$ it is automatic. I brought the derivative into the picture for the sole purpose of computing the gcd, and not having to guess the value of $\alpha$.

Comment: Running Euclid's algorithm for the general quartic above leaves me with $d(x)$ that is independent of $x$, i.e., involving only the terms $a,b,c,d,e$. I'm guessing this term must be $0$ so that the previous step (linear term) in the algorithm will be the GCD. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes. A general quartic will not have a double root, so a constant gcd is to be expected. You get a condition for the the existence of a double root by setting that quantity to zero. If the gcd were of degree $>1$ (you don't want that to happen), then the polynomial of the previous step would also be zero.